# Extract SQL Parameter names from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm implementing my own DBCommand like wrapper for our proprietary database through which we can only access via API and by using strings. Boooo

I want to be able to find via Regular Expression my normal parameters and not select the @@IDENTITY field (or anything else like that). I'm then going to replace the parameter name with the real value of that parameter `NULL` or `'Some Value'` etc.

Currently I have

```
@\w{1,}
```

Given a string

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(VALUE1, VALUE2) VALUES (@MyValue1, @MyValue2); SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

I'm matching

```
@MyValue1
@MyValue2
@IDENTITY
```

I also tried `[^@]@\w{1,}` but it matches `(@MyValue1` and `_@MyValue2` (underscore representing space)

How can I not match @@Identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,i assume this what you want.

```
(?<!@)@\w+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add paretheses, marking the subexpression whose matching string you actually want to use: `[^@](@\w{1,})`, then use `Match.Groups(1)` to retrieve that part only.

Another variant is a negative look-behind assertion: `(?<!@)@\w{1,}`, with an additional bonus of matching `@name` in the very beginning of the string (well, it probably won't happen).

Update: and it won't help you for `'@quoted @string @literals'`, which are *legitimate SQL*, but not *parameters*

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure it doesn't start with 2 `@`:

```
(?<!@)@\w{1,}
```